# Is there a way to push sound from PC to wifi speakers?

Tags: wireless-networking

I bought omni 10. I bought that because it supports wifi connections.

My android smartphone can play song via wifi to that omni speakers.

But my computer cannot.

Strange right?

How do I send sound straight from computer to harman kardon wifi?

Note: This is important because using bluetooth means result is very choppy. But the problem could be on my bluetooth. There are tons of complaints that sounds from bluetooth are choppy. I also uses 3.5 mm AUX cable. But there seems to be 2 seconds sound latency.

Comment: You need bluetooth in your computer.

Comment: They are not wifi speakers, they are bluetooth speakers.  Have you paired the speakers with your computer via bluetooth?

Comment: The result is very choppy. But the problem could be on my bluetooth. There are tons of complaints that sounds from bluetooth are choppy. I also uses 3.5 mm AUX cable. But there seems to be 2 seconds sound latency.

Comment: Are there such things a wifi speakers?

Answer (score 0):

what I did was purchase an Adapt (harman kardon) and plug it into one of the outputs of my office computer. On the computer I set it up as a stereo pair of front speakers. That way I can setup a playlist at the desktop and send it around the house.

Another option is to plug a chromecast audio dongle into the speaker and broadcast that way. I found a program called Airparrot that helps with that but it's a bit buggy so the adapt is my go to.